# Need help in deciding on a video editor

Tags: windows, video-editing, comparison

I currently use Resolve 17 on my PC but I have noticed that it really lags when I try to play the video in preview.
It got me thinking, while Resolve is really powerful I barely use majority of it's features.

So I am thinking of switching to something else, so I my options currently are Shotcut or Hit Film Express.

My requirements would be : Basic Editing and Motion Graphics.
I don't think the content I produce ever uses Color Grading or High level of Effects.

If you guys can recommend good editing software that fulfill those requirement , it would be great.

Operating System - Windows 10.

Comment: My magical crystal ball is out of order, so which Operating System are we talking about?  

Comment: Have you checked your proxy media is correct & on a fast-enough drive. If you're not actually using high-end FX in daVinci, it's not using any resources they would need. Video editing is a high-resource task & many [most] regular consumer computers will struggle if the proxies are not set up properly [This goes 4-fold for 4k video, your average consumer lappy will struggle with regular HD]

Comment: @Tetsujin how can I check?

Comment: ermm… well… tbh it's a tad complex, as most of DaVinci is, but it's all there in the [manual](https://documents.blackmagicdesign.com/UserManuals/DaVinci_Resolve_17_Reference_Manual.pdf) It starts at Chapter 8. I guess that's the trouble with using one of the most comprehensive editors in existence, but it's honestly worth knowing how it all works. If you start out in one of the consumer suites & need one extra feature it doesn't have, then you're stuck. If you do it in DaVinci, the feature will be there.

Answer (score 2):

My magical crystal ball is out of order, so I just assume, that you are not using Linux....

Your requirements are "Basic Editing" and "Motion Graphics". So, basically, you are fine with every single video editing software out there.

Then why not use what you already have? If you have a recent Mac or PC (Windows), you have preinstalled video editing software:

- iMovie (Mac)
- Video Editor (Windows)
- Clipchamp (Windows 11)

Video-Editor is the successor of Windows Movie Maker. Movie Maker has a really bad reputation, but compared to what you ask for, Video-Editor is really not a bad choice.

Clipchamp is preinstalled on Windows 11 (again, if you don't specify what operating system you have, I have to guess). It offers great options to edit and for motion graphics and is template based, so it's easy to use.

Comment: It's Windows 10 , sorry I forgot to specify the OS. Will I be able to go to heaven?

Comment: @Rushil you might have a chance: edit your question and fill the gaps. There're rumours that some users got absolution that way :D

Answer (score 0):

In my experience [kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/) handles the preview pretty wel. Its also not really complex for a video editor and is quite capable in terms of features.

Answer (score 0):

Do try using the free version of the VSDC video editor that is available from https://www.videosoftdev.com/. I have been using its basic abilities for some months now with excellent results; I have just checked to find that it also does motion graphics.